# Python program export from txt file

Tags: python

When I get the printer output in .txt format, I need to make a script that will seek for some values (how much printer takes black, yellow colors etc.) than export it to another txt file.

It doesn't need to be python but I just need some tutorial where I can learn how to do that.

Comment: It's better to have a clearer example of your question

Comment: Please post a sample output.txt, along with a information on what you want to extract. Also include a code sample with your attempt. [SO guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is my output and i need to export marked text to other text file http://i57.tinypic.com/2njdr1y.jpg

Comment: You better paste the file content within your question (use the "edit" function) instead of posting a link to a photo. And, please, define the desired result with a meaningful example.

Comment: I don't have that file right now on computer.

Answer (score 0):

I founded solution with this:

```
f=open('filename')
lines=f.readlines()
print lines[#]
print lines[#]
```